# How can I get the date at which the issue was assigned to a user, using the GitHub API?

Tags: github-api

I am trying to get the date at which an issue was assigned to a user in Github, using Github API.

Went through
https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/ and
https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/

Also checked in https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/ but it was not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the [issue API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html) mentioned "assigned_date".

You can get the issues assigned to a given user, but without knowing when each issue was assigned to said user.
Meaning: that "event" (assigning an issue to a user) does not trigger a date recording.